# How to handle exceptions in the code async using nested functions?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to handle the exception thrown, after the execution of a stack of functions.
I want to put the `try/catch` block on top of the call stack, and the exception thrown is in an asynchronous code, created by `Task.Run` method.
The code that I'm using to try to treat the code is as follows:

```
static async Task Send()
    {
        try
        {
            await SendEmailAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    static Task<Boolean> SendEmailAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
            SendEmail());
    }

    static Boolean SendEmail()
    {
        throw new Exception("message of exception");
    }
```

What the best form of handle the `Exception` thrown in the method `SendEmail`, so that the treatment becomes the `Send` method?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The code you posted is catching the exception, right?

Comment: Side note: using `Task.Run` to create fake asynchronous methods is a [code smell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx).

Comment: this code nothing handle exception..

Comment: what best pratice, to create async code?

Comment: Are you saying that the `Send` method is not catching the exception?

Comment: yes, it is not catching the exception, you have any solution?

Comment: I'm quite sure it is catching exceptions. See this: https://ideone.com/8gV4O7

Comment: How can you tell it is not catching the exception?

Comment: In the real console app is not working...

Comment: Can you show complete (but as small as possible) sample demonstrating the issue? There is a good chance that you are doing something wrong when calling the methods.

Comment: this sample not catching exception in my console application..

Comment: @NicolasDias you have not posted a complete sample as requested. Also, repeating the same statement you made multiple times already does nothing to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your commen you said:

> In the real console app is not working...

I guess you have a code like this

```
public static void Main()
{
    Send();
}
```

This will cause the asynchronous code to start and because you don't wait for it to end, your app is immadiately closed. So of course you will not see your exception throwing, because app is already closed.

Try this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Send().Wait();
}
```

This will cause your main method to until task ends.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013, when the method SendEmail is executed the exception is thrown, and the dialog of exception is show.

Comment: @NicolasDias you still have not posted your full code and have not reacted to such comments. The question should be closed because you are not cooperating. It is unanswerable.

Answer (score -1):

This code does catch the exception. You are just running it in a console application like this:

```
void Main() { Send(); }
```

Main exits and the process terminates before exception processing can take place. Use `Send().Wait();`.